# Analyzing Likert Scale already Coded in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this

```
Case   process   clear
 1      5         5
 2      5         3
 3      3         5
```

I can't figure out the life of me how to get a frequency of process that has 5(very satisifed), 4(satisfied) and include the percentage of it.

What I want is:
   Find the percentage that cases are satisfied with these case process.

```
66% of the process are very satisfied. 2 cases were very satisfied with the process out of 3.
```

Comment: Do you mean you just want a percent distribution? Possibly with labels? `prop.table(df$process)`  There are also a lot of packages with different variations of crosstabs and tables.

Comment: I wasn't clear, but I want to be able to calculate the above. 66% of the process are very satisfied. 2 cases were very satisfied with the process out of 3 @elin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a new data frame with the tabulated values, then calculate the proportions based on that.

tab.table<-as.data.frame(table(data$process))

tab.table$proportions<-tab.table$Freq/length(data$process)